# Перегрузить декремент

Tags: c#

Имеется функция извлечения элемента из стека

```
    public int Pop()
    {
        if (counter == 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Stack is empty");

        int item = arr[--counter];
        return item;
    }
```

Необходимо перегрузить -- для извлечения. Как это сделать?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading

Comment: Вы уверены, что в этом есть смысл? Во всех пособиях рекомендуют не трогать операторы так как те кто будет ими пользоваться может словить вынос мозга из-за неожиданности

Comment: Нет, у чужого типа перегрузить оператор нельзя. Но я и не понял зачем вам это, опишите подробнее, вроде нормальный код.